# Java replace characters with uppercase around (before and after) specific character

Tags: java, regex, uppercase, apostrophe

I have this kind of input

```
word w'ord wo'rd
```

I need to convert to uppercase both characters at the starts of the word and right after the `'` character (which can exists multiple times).

The output I need (using the previous example) is

```
word W'Ord Wo'Rd
```

I tried with a simple pattern

```
s.replaceAll("(\\w)(\\w*)'(\\w)", "$1");
```

but I'm unable to convert the group 1 and 3 to uppercase

---

EDIT:
After I discovered a little mistake in the main question, I edited @Wiktor Stribizew code in order to include the case I missed.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w)(\\w*)'(\\w)").matcher(s);
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(1).toUpperCase() + m.group(2) + "'" + m.group(3).toUpperCase());
}
m.appendTail(result);
s = result.toString();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `Matcher#appendReplacement` in Java to be able to process the match. Here is an example:

```
String s = "word w'ord wo'rd";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w)(\\w*)'(\\w(?:'\\w)*)").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, 
        m.group(1).toUpperCase()+m.group(2) + "'" + m.group(3).toUpperCase());
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
// => word W'Ord Wo'Rd
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/zPRWyy)

Java 9+ equivalent ([demo](https://ideone.com/acyZI6)):

```
String s = "wo'rd w'ord wo'r'd";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w)(\\w*)'(\\w(?:'\\w)*)").matcher(s);
System.out.println(
    m.replaceAll(r -> r.group(1).toUpperCase()+r.group(2) + "'" + r.group(3).toUpperCase())
);
//wo'rd w'ord wo'r'd => Wo'Rd W'Ord Wo'R'D
//word w'ord wo'rd => word W'Ord Wo'Rd
```

**Pattern break-down**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(\w)` - Group 1: a single word char
- `(\w*)` - Group 2: zero or more word chars
- `'` - a single quote
- `(\w(?:'\w)*)` - Group 3:

  - `\w` - a word char
  - `(?:'\w)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `'` - a single quote
    - `\w` - a word char.

Now, if you want to make the pattern more precise, you can change the `\w` that are supposed to match lowercase letters with `\p{Ll}` and the `\w` that is supposed to match any letter with `\p{L}`. The pattern would look like `"(?U)\\b(\\p{Ll})(\\p{L}*)'(\\p{Ll}(?:'\\p{Ll})*)"` - however, you risk to leave letters in lowercase (those after `'`) if there are uppercase before lowercase ones (like in `wo'r'D's` -> `Wo'R'D's`). `(?U)` is a `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` inline modifier that makes `\b` word boundary Unicode-aware.

Comment: This works indeed. Running this code and seeing the output on all the lines I need to convert, I discovered a little mistake in the main question. I now adjusted the main question in order to include the case I missed

Comment: Fails for string :  String s = "wo'rd w'ord wo'r'd";

Comment: @DevilingMaster: The same approach is valid here: capture what you need into groups, then manipulate each group as you need inside the `while` block.

Comment: @Optional: Not a problem, use `"\\b(\\w)(\\w*)'(\\w(?:'\\w)*)"` regex.

Comment: Yes, @WiktorStribiżew yes, got it

Comment: A good question to ask in interview, where restricting them to use "patterns" and regex :)

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as @Wiktor Stribizew post above but an attempt to do without regex:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String s ="word w'ord wo'r'd";
    System.out.println(upperCase(s,'\''));
 }
 private static int x = 1;
 private static String upperCase(String originalString, char delimeter)
 {
     if(originalString.length()==1)
     {
         return originalString;
     }
     int indexOfDelimeter = originalString.indexOf(delimeter);
     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     if(indexOfDelimeter<0)
     {
         return originalString;
     }
     String newBaseString = originalString.substring(indexOfDelimeter+2);
     if(indexOfDelimeter==0)
     {
         result.append(delimeter).append(Character.toUpperCase(originalString.charAt(indexOfDelimeter+1))).append(newBaseString);
     }
     else
     {
         result.append(originalString.substring(0,indexOfDelimeter-1)).append(Character.toUpperCase(originalString.charAt(indexOfDelimeter-1))).append(delimeter).append(Character.toUpperCase(originalString.charAt(indexOfDelimeter+1)));
     }
     if(indexOfDelimeter<originalString.length())
     {
        result.append(upperCase( newBaseString,delimeter));
     }
     return result.toString();
 }
}
```