# Java - Converting character of string to uppercase using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I need to convert the characters followed by a `-` in a string to uppercase.

Using Regex101, the following works like a charm:

```regex
Regex -> (\-[a-z]|\_[a-z])
Substitution -> \U$1
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rXV38S/1)

But I don't know how to properly translate this to a Java RegEx. Here's what I got so far:

```java
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("this-is-a_test");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\-[a-z]|\\_[a-z])");
p.matcher(str).replaceAll("\\p{Lu}$1");

System.out.println(str);
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might shorten your pattern to `([-_])([a-z])` https://regex101.com/r/gu83Cr/1 and I think you can see this answer to convert the second capturing group to uppercase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467120/java-replace-characters-with-uppercase-around-before-and-after-specific-charac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [`public String replaceAll​(String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) doesn't modify *source text* used by Matcher, but it returns *new* (separate) String with replaced content based on original text passed to matcher. So `p.matcher(str).replaceAll("\\p{Lu}$1");` will not modify `str` but will return new String which you are ignoring.
2. Also `.replaceAll("\\p{Lu}$1")` doesn't treat `\\p{Lu}` as indicator of uppercase change like `\U` does in JavaScript. Java's regular expression engine is different beast and `\\p{Lu}` in replacement is treated as simple string without special meaning, so your code would result in `thisp{Lu}-isp{Lu}-ap{Lu}_test`.

If you want to easily generate dynamic replacement **based on current match** you can use [`public String replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) added in Java 9. This way you can provide implementation of `Function<MatchResult,​String>` functional interface with lambda like `match -> /*code using match and returning proper replacement*/`

In your case it can look like:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("this-is-a_test");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[-_][a-z]");
String replaced = p.matcher(str).replaceAll(match -> match.group(0).toUpperCase());
System.out.println(replaced);
```

which results in `this-Is-A_Test`.

BTW I simplified your regex to `[-_][a-z]` since IMO it is easier to understand.